# Overriding named routes provided by Rails 3 Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-engines

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 3(.0) application that uses a Rails engine. However, in my local application, I want to override one of the routes provided by the Rails engine.

From the engine config/routes.rb:

```
match 'their_named_route' => 'controller#action', :as => 'the_route'
```

From my application config/routes.rb:

```
match 'my_named_route' => 'controller#action', :as => 'the_route'
```

However, when I inspect the routes, both seem to be active (and their route appears to "win", at least within the engine controllers)

```
$ rake routes
the_route  /my_named_route(.:format)    {:controller=>"controller", :action=>"action"}
the_route  /their_named_route(.:format) {:controller=>"controller", :action=>"action"}
```

Is there a good way to force my local application's named route to take priority?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's no such easy way. The routes are defined in `lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:271`, which calls add_route on the RouteSet (defined in `rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb`, and on line 71 the name is attached). There's no remove_route method, and the Engine's route is added last. You can add your route manually after the application is initialized with Rails.application.routes.draw instead of having it in routes.rb, or you can patch the Engine.

Comment: That confirms my fears; if an alternative answer isn't provided soon, I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I got around this by moving my engine's routes from config/routes.rb to a class method in the engine class itself:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    def self.routes
      MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
        resources :products
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then in the base app's routes file:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # Routes for base app including the ones overriding MyEngine::Engine.

  MyEngine::Engine.routes
end
```

I can then happily override any routes in the base app with those in the engine.

Note that the overriding routes need to be defined before the overridden routes since the earlier defined routes take precedence over later ones.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to override a route within an engine. Instead, you must define an overruling route. You can do this by calling `prepend` on the engine's router:

```
An::Engine.routes.prepend do
  root :to => "somewhere#action"
end
```

If the engine's namespace is isolated, this will use the `SomewhereController` from inside the engine's namespace. If not, it will use the typical `SomewhereController`.

If you want to override a route to return a 404, the best way I can think of is to redirect to a 404 page:

```
match "/route_goes_here" => redirect("/404")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need add initializer hook to config/application.rb, like this:

```
class Application < Rails::Application

  config.encoding = "utf-8"

  ...

  initializer :add_routing_paths do |app|
    their_routes_path = app.routes_reloader.paths.select{|path| path =~ /DIR/}.first
    app.routes_reloader.paths.delete(their_routes_path)
    app.routes_reloader.paths.unshift(their_routes_path)
  end
end
```

It's load roues.rb of you engine first and you can override their routes.

Comment: I'm having trouble confirming this actually works, but it also seems dangerous/confusing/ugly. I suppose the "right" approach would be to make the modify the engine to expose a method that can be called within the application config/routes.rb

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend routes as suggest by Ryan Bigg above. I found that in order overrule the named route helper with my custom route I need to call `append` instead of `prepend`, like so:

```
An::Engine.routes.append do
  root :to => "somewhere#action"
end
```

Otherwise the app contains both routes and the named helper for engine's router is the last definition, and therefore the one that is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Routing rules defined in routes.rb are applied from the top down until a match is found.  I was able to override the route defined in the mounted engine simply by moving the higher-priority rule *above* the line where the engine is mounted.  So,

```html
get 'about', controller: 'static', action: 'about', as: 'about'
mount My::Engine => '/'
```

results in the app routing /about/ requests to (in this case) the static controller, whereas:

```html
mount My::Engine => '/'
get 'about', controller: 'static', action: 'about', as: 'about'
```

results in the app routing /about/ requests to the route defined in the mounted engine.

Answer (score 0):

To Replace the default routes path provided by gem or engine we can achive that in following way.
For me I wanted to replace 'spree_user' with 'account' etc from all routes
/user/**spree_user**/sign_in   I did this in following way

Step 1
Create config/some_engine_route_override.rb
Copy the content of engine route file and update the routes as per need

Step 2
in application.rb use the folllowing hook

```
# Override Spree Core routes in order to translate products routes
initializer "delete_spree_core_routes", after: "add_routing_paths" do |app|
  new_spree_auth_route_path = File.expand_path('../../config/some_engine_route_override.rb', __FILE__)
  routes_paths = app.routes_reloader.paths

  spree_devise_auth_route_path = routes_paths.select{ |path| path.include?("spree_auth_devise") }.first

  if spree_devise_auth_route_path.present?
    spree_core_route_path_index = routes_paths.index(spree_devise_auth_route_path)

    routes_paths.delete_at(spree_core_route_path_index)
  
    routes_paths.insert(spree_core_route_path_index, new_spree_auth_route_path)
   
  end
end
```